# Logo, screen resolution

Tags: html, css

My questions:
1.Logo: I'm trying to put my logo in top left side of my navigation but I can't. Any ideas (NOT UP TO CHANGE CODE A LOT)?
2.Screen resolution: Well I've noticed that my website isn't same on my PC and Laptop (ofc...). Is it possible to some how fix that. On this pictures you can also see how my website looks with my fonts. So you can see better that problem with Logo.

```css
  body {
   background-color: white;                
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   min-width: 1000px;
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "Jocker";
   src: url("JockeyOne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "Pacifica";
   src: url("PacificaCondensed-Regular.ttf") format

("truetype"); 
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "ReklameScript";
   src:url("ReklameScript.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  h1 {
   font-size: 120px;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: "Jocker";
   margin-left: 45;
   color: rgb(200,101, 103);
  }  

  h2 {
   font-size: 70;
   margin-left: 224;
   font-family: "Jocker";
   color: rgb(200,101, 103);
  }

  #header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   margin: auto;
 
  }
  
  #navigacija {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 50px;  
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: right;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #089DE3;
   z-index: 9999;   
  }
  
  #navigacija a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 50px; 
   font-size: 30px; 
   font-family: "Pacifica";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
 
  #navigacija a:hover {
   background: #00C5CD;
  }

  .main1 {
   margin-top: 50px;
   font-family: "ReklameScript";
   font-size: 50;
   background: #089DE3;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 194;
  }
  
  .video-container {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   padding-top: 0px;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   bottom: 930;
   right: 0px;
  }
  .video-container iframe,  
  .video-container object,  
  .video-container embed {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
  .video-wrapper {
   width: 640px;
   float: right;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>MaxSkins-Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
 
 

 </head>

<body>
 <div id="header">
 <div id="navigacija">
       <a href="Home.html"><div class="Home"><b>HOME</b></div></a> 
       <a href="Shop.html"><b>SHOP</b></a> 
       <a href="#"><b>GET POINTS</b></a> 
       <a href="#"><b>INFO</b></a> 
   </div>
 </div>

  <h1><b>EARN POINTS,<br> GET SKINS!</b></h1>
  <h2><b>How does it work?</b></h2>
 <div class="main1">
  <p><b>It's simple!<br> Watch videos, do tasks and have fun!

<br>After earning large amount of coins,<br> contact us to get your skins!

<b></p>
 
 </div>

 <div class="video-wrapper">
 <div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="640" height="360" 

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lwItL2NXwDw" frameborder="5" 

allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <!-- /video -->
</div>
<!-- /video-wrapper --> 
</body>
</html>
```

[1680x1050](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXSOa.jpg) [1366x768](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Thy.jpg)

Comment: Looks like this is one of those "earn money fast in the internet pages"? Impressive.

Comment: When you say, "NOT UP TO CHANGE CODE A LOT", that indicates you just want someone to code up a quick answer for you and not do any work. Perhaps you should approach this as a learning experience and analyze your code to see if there are more efficient ways to lay this out.

Comment: @WillCarron Not correct, I know some people who when they try to help they change you're whole code... I just need some ideas... Well I'm just doing this for learning experience. My friend made this quick site on wixsites and told me to try make something similar to this... https://prodajarpsrbija.wixsite.com/maxskins

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this. As I've seen in the site you linked, the logo is formatted text. I inserted text with left float. See if that works for you.

```css
  body {
   background-color: white;                
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   min-width: 1000px;
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "Jocker";
   src: url("JockeyOne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "Pacifica";
   src: url("PacificaCondensed-Regular.ttf") format

("truetype"); 
  }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "ReklameScript";
   src:url("ReklameScript.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  h1 {
   font-size: 120px;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: "Jocker";
   margin-left: 45;
   color: rgb(200,101, 103);
  }  

  h2 {
   font-size: 70;
   margin-left: 224;
   font-family: "Jocker";
   color: rgb(200,101, 103);
  }

  #header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   margin: auto;
 
  }
  
  #navigacija {
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   height: 50px;  
   overflow: hidden;
   text-align: right;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #089DE3;
   z-index: 9999;   
  }
  
  #navigacija a {
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 50px; 
   font-size: 30px; 
   font-family: "Pacifica";
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 50px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-top: 0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  a#logo {
   float: left;
  }
 
  #navigacija a:hover {
   background: #00C5CD;
  }

  .main1 {
   margin-top: 50px;
   font-family: "ReklameScript";
   font-size: 50;
   background: #089DE3;
   text-align: left;
   margin-left: 194;
  }
  
  .video-container {
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   padding-top: 0px;
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   bottom: 930;
   right: 0px;
  }
  .video-container iframe,  
  .video-container object,  
  .video-container embed {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
  .video-wrapper {
   width: 640px;
   float: right;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>MaxSkins-Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
 
 

 </head>

<body>
 <div id="header">
 <div id="navigacija">
       <a href="#" id="logo">LOGO</a>
       <a href="Home.html"><div class="Home"><b>HOME</b></div></a> 
       <a href="Shop.html"><b>SHOP</b></a> 
       <a href="#"><b>GET POINTS</b></a> 
       <a href="#"><b>INFO</b></a> 
   </div>
 </div>

  <h1><b>EARN POINTS,<br> GET SKINS!</b></h1>
  <h2><b>How does it work?</b></h2>
 <div class="main1">
  <p><b>It's simple!<br> Watch videos, do tasks and have fun!

<br>After earning large amount of coins,<br> contact us to get your skins!

<b></p>
 
 </div>

 <div class="video-wrapper">
 <div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="640" height="360" 

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lwItL2NXwDw" frameborder="5" 

allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <!-- /video -->
</div>
<!-- /video-wrapper --> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could, consider accepting my answer so it may help other people in the future. ;)